# calculate spectators sum from table

Tags: sql, postgresql

Table Games

```
Home |  Visitor    | Spectators
-----------------------------------
a    |    b        |   12
b    |    c        |   15  
a    |    c        |   32
b    |    a        |   3
c    |    a        |   8
```

Table Teams

```
id  |  name
--------------
a   |  TeamA
b   |  TeamB
c   |  TeamC
```

Now I need to calculate each teams total spectators (home + visitor)

- A = 12+12+3+8
- B = 12+15+3

Comment: Where does the second `12` come from for TeamA?  Shouldn't that be 12+32+3+8?

Comment: What have you tried? this looks like a homework assignment.

Comment: it's not homework, I'm just quite novice with sql.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are plenty of ways to do it, here is another:

```
SELECT name,sum(sum)
FROM
    (SELECT t.name,SUM(g.spectators)
    FROM teams t, games g WHERE t.id=home
    GROUP BY t.name
    UNION
    SELECT t.name,SUM(g.spectators)
    FROM teams t, games g WHERE t.id=visitor
    GROUP BY t.name)visits
GROUP BY name
```

Answer (score 0):

Does it need to be formatted in the way displayed for Table Teams? If not, this should work for you:

```
select top 1 
    (select sum(spectators) from sheet1 where home='a' or visitor='a') as teama,
    (select sum(spectators) from sheet1 where home='b' or visitor='b') as teamb,
    (select sum(spectators) from sheet1 where home='c' or visitor='c') as teamc 
from sheet1;
```

This will output as:

```
teama     teamb     teamc
55        30        55
```

Comment: Format as table Teams is what I'm looking for